# Select query limit the column characters not more than 100

Tags: mysql

Currently, I have this select query where its selecting films details from the database. Now i am trying to limit the `description` column to only select 100 characters for display purpose. Are there any way to do this. Thanks in advance.

This is my current SQL query:

```
"SELECT title, description, release_year, rating, f.last_update, c.name FROM nfc_film f 
 INNER JOIN nfc_film_category fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
 INNER JOIN nfc_category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
 ORDER BY title";
```

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(col) > 100 THEN CONCAT(LEFT(col, 100), '(...)') ELSE col END AS col ...`

Comment: Why case? `SELECT LEFT(col,100) AS col`....

Comment: @sagi because you wouldn't add ellipsis except where necessary (I would use 97 instead of 100 for the CONCAT)

Comment: `Length` is more efficient then `left`? @Strawberry ?

Comment: @sagi I don't understand the question. We need to know the length in order to determine whether or not the string is more or less than 100 characters (well, actually bytes). If it is, shorten it and add ellipsis.

Comment: He didn't ask for `...` where its longer then 100 characters, so each time it will perform `LENGTH` and sometimes it will perform `LEFT` in addition. So  unless `length` is more efficient, only `LEFT` will be better. @Strawberry

Comment: @sagi You wanted to know why CASE was used, so I explained why.

Comment: I didn't want to know why case was used, I wanted to mention that its not necessarily  @Strawberry

Comment: i tried the code given by @JaydipJ but its showing syntax error. Before this it worked but then the decription which has more than 100 characters showed 0 as the description. can i know whats the problem actually

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring function, as shown below:

SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)

str : The string you want to cut.
pos : Starting position from where you want to cut.
len : Length in characters, up to where you need to cut.

Hope it helps

```
SELECT title, 
   CASE 
       WHEN LENGTH(description) > 100 THEN SUBSTRING(description, 1, 100) 
       ELSE description 
   END AS 'description', 
   release_year, 
   rating, 
   f.last_update, 
   c.name
FROM nfc_film f
INNER JOIN nfc_film_category fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id 
INNER JOIN nfc_category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id 
ORDER BY title;
```

Comment: @anonymous5671 what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: substring' ` This is the error message i am receiving

Comment: can you try substr once?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `LEFT` and `IF` function to achieve that:

```
SELECT title,
    CONCAT(LEFT(description,100), 
           IF(length(description) > 100, '...', '')) as description,
    release_year, rating, f.last_update, c.name FROM nfc_film f 
INNER JOIN nfc_film_category fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
INNER JOIN nfc_category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
ORDER BY title
```

Comment: i tried still the same syntax error `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near &quot;(&quot;: syntax error'`

Comment: my bad. another typo. try again.